# Refreshing SQL database

Tags: android, sql

I'm using a DatabaseHelper class to load up a SQLite database. If it doesn't already exist, it will create it. The XML file used to create the database is in a specific folder on the sdcard.

I would like to RELOAD the sql database from the XML file via a menu. I have the menu setup, but can't seem to find a way to reload the SQL. Is there an easy way to do this without having to uninstall the app and reinstall which removes/recreates the database.

Here's the code from my DatabaseHelper:

```
package samples.myApp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "projectDocuments";

    protected Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String s;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Database Created", 2000).show();
            // Old database loaded from res
            //InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
            // Load from sdcard
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/ContractHound/sql.xml");

            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                db.execSQL(s);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 90000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS documents");
        onCreate(db);
    }   
}
```

Comment: May be if u call activity Once again than that is also possible.

Comment: That doesn't work since the databasehelper sees that the database is existing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to invoke `onUpgrade`? If so, you could increase db version in constructor

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
```

or programmatically

```
getWritableDatabase().setVersion(2);
```

**Edited**

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.setVersion(db.getVersion()+1);
```

Something like that. However i've never incremented db version other than by hardcoding it.
And don't forget to close your `db` in `onStop` or somewhere else by calling `db.close()` or `dbHelper.close()`.
There's also method [needUpgrade (int newVersion)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#needUpgrade%28int%29) that has no javadoc, you could try to play with it.

Comment: ernazm, I think the onUpgrade would work, but those are hardcoding the version number. I assume I could use a getVersion and then just increment by one, right?
How do I properly call the getWritableDatabase().setVersion(2); from my separate class (This is my first java program)?

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. created an onStop function and put in a db.close(); The program crashes when it goes back to that activity. Do I need to add something to onResume() in order to open the database back up?

Comment: I even tried
   File file = new File("/data/data/projectDocuments");
   file.delete();
but that didn't work either. I had assumed that if the database didn't exist that it would create a new one, but for some reason it won't delete it. Arg!

Comment: OK, got it working by using deleteDatabase("database_name");
Yeah! I'm sure it's not the most elegant solution, but it works.